# Update Typescript to v3.2.1, No tsc.exe in SDK Folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am developing an Angular project using Visual Studio 2017 and have been trying to update Typescript to v3.2.1. I downloaded the installer from Microsoft and installed it. Looking within the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.2` folder I noticed that there was not a `tsc.exe` file. I looked back in my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.1` folder where there is a `tsc.exe` file.

To inform Visual Studio of the new version I adjusted the path in my Environment Variables > System Variables to point to the new `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.2\` folder. After this change the command `tsc -v` no longer works. Is this because there is no `tsc.exe` file within the folder?

What is confusing me is the option to install Typescript using NPM which appears to install it into my `user/AppData/Roaming/npm` folder. Should I do both?

Any advice would be very welcome.

Comment: Related:  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28761

Comment: Thanks Amy, that's very helpful. Still unsure if I should use the Microsoft Installer, use `npm install...`, or both!

Answer (score 0):

From version 3.2, you need to install tsc.exe separately.

1. Right click on your project and go to "Manage Nuget Packages...";
2. Find and install Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler;

The tsc.exe file will be in the folder:
[project root]\packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler[version number]\tools